# Listener on AccessDenied due to maximum session reached in SpringSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In my application, I have `maximumSessions` set to **1** and `sessionFixation` set to **none**. Now I would like to send message on topic that informs about another login attempt.
How do I do that? Do I listen on `SessionCreationEvent` and spawn message when session count is > 1? Does the `maximumSessions=1` and `sessionFixation=none` means that no other session can be created as long as the first one lives?

Edit:

Thanks to @M. Deinum I have the answer which is to set `http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)`. `maxSessionPreventsLogin` sets `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy::exceptionIfMaximumExceeded` internally to true, which results in throwing `SessionAuthenticationException` when user tries to log in over the limit.

Thamks SO!

Comment: Those are sessions per user... Spring Security will send an event (not sure which one) when this occurs.

Comment: Yes, I want to have maximum of one session per user

Comment: Well as stated, you already have an event for that which you can listen to with an `ApplicationListener`.

Comment: What exactly is that event? Could be `SessionFixationProtectionEvent` ?

Comment: No that is for the fixation. My bad as it will throw an exception the `SessionAuthenticationException` for which you could write a dedicated `FailureHandler` (probably extend the one you use now to retrain the original behavior). For the exception to work you would have to switch the `exceptionIfMaximumExceeded` to `true` (the default is `false`).

Comment: Ok now I see, it throws `SessionAuthenticationException` if `ConcurrencyControlConfigurer::maxSessionsPreventsLogin` is set to true. Thank you, I think this is what I need.